# How do I delete any row from all excel sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

How do I remove row from all sheets who is having values `Id`

all sheets are having `Id` row as position `2nd`.

So I could I remove `2nd row` from all excel sheets?

Please guide me and give me any link ?

thanks

below code working good but only for open sheet .

> how do I loop through each sheets from workbook ?

```
 Sub demo()

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ashish.fugat\Desktop\demo.xlsx")

i = 1

Do Until objExcel.Cells(i, 2).Value = ""
    If objExcel.Cells(i, 2).Value = "Id" Then
        Set objRange = objExcel.Cells(i, 2).EntireRow
        objRange.Delete
        i = i - 1
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: show us please whst have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried one macro but it is not working

Comment: can you clarify how it's not working?

Comment: Its not working and I google it and tried to modify this 1 , could anyone help me in this ? i new to excel and macro

Comment: You only want to remove all `2nd Row` in all Sheets? Or is the `Cell` containing `Id` is different between sheets?

Comment: I only want to delete 2nd row from all sheets

Comment: `I only want to delete 2nd row from all sheets` I don't see any problem..have you tried to [record a macro](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/macro-recorder.html)?

Comment: I have gone through it .. but I dont know how it works to delete 2nd row , could you help me?

Comment: Updated my code please let me know how do I loop through all sheets.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through all worksheets in a workbook using this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub LoopThroughWorksheets()

'declare a worksheet to loop through the workbook with
Dim SheetIdx As Worksheet

For Each SheetIdx In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    '
    'do stuff here
    '
    'for example, if you wanted to show the name of each sheet
    'in the workbook, you could add the following line:
    MsgBox (SheetIdx.Name)
Next SheetIdx

End Sub
```